# Cpanel Yandex MX Error

Tags: email, hosting, cpanel, mx-record, yandex

I want to transfer my e-mail accounts to Yandex. I use Cpanel at hosting server. 
I get an error when adding Yandex mx addresses, "**mx.yandex.net.**" I can't add address with dot. Error says: "It must have a valid TLD tag." I stuck here.

[image]

Comment: Documentation (https://yandex.com/support/domain/set-mail/mx.html) says: " In some control panels, the dot is assumed automatically. In this case, you don't need to add it". Have you tried removing the last dot in "mx.yandex.net."?

Comment: I tried. But yandex did not approve.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I could manage to fix it by deleting all old MX records and adding a new one 
Priority: 10
Destination: mx.yandex.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AypEu.png)

You also need to add the TXT record

v=spf1 redirect=_spf.yandex.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX0ez.png)